# Applying regression models in R

Tags: r

So, this is a question that I wish to ask. I was reading about linear regression and stuff. I understood that linear regression basically associates two variables with each other. I have a doubt on its applicability if it can be applied somehow in my case as well.

So, assume I have 10 files. Each file basically contains 1000's of rows and 3 columns. The first two columns basically represent the nodes (as in a graph) and the third column gives a rule that the nodes follow. Let us assume the rule as any sequence of 1's and 0's mixed together.

Sample:

```
 Node 1     Node 2     Rule
   2          3        110
   3          4        110
..........................
```

Another file contains nodes for another rule. Is there any way I can apply some regression model on any of the parametres in R?

Comment: You don't offer much detail to go on, but regressions typically (not always) have a continuous dependent variable. Your rule is categorical, so this sounds more like some tree structure

Comment: Please help me to improve upon this. I will be glad to give more information. And what kind of tree structure do you propose and how can it actually help me in analysing the data more effectively? Any example that comes to your mind right now? Thanks. :)

Comment: If you have a table associating nodes based on some set of rules, you should really read up on the `igraph` and `network` packages.